# Category theory textbook for Banach algebras and Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, category-theory, operator-algebras, book-recommendation

Do you know of a textbook at the graduate level about the common categories of functional analysis (such as the 2 categories of Banach spaces, the 2 categories of Banach algebras, the category of Banach modules, the category of C$^*$-algebras, the category of W$^*$-algebras) which is suitable for a student who has taken a basic course in category theory?

The *ideal* book covers the basic themes such as injective, projective, flat objects; limits & colimits; tensor products; injective envelopes; etc. of each category in the category theoretical context, with their context-specific equivalent definitions. It would be instructive if the book contains examples for the (existence and) non-existence results.

I can't blame if you think that I have way too many criteria for the ideal book, so I can't match up with a great book that would fill up the gap in my life and my bookshelf.

Comment: Try this book! https://digital.lib.washington.edu/researchworks/bitstream/handle/1773/16302/C-star.pdf

Comment: @fosco This is just a book about $C^*$-algebras?

Comment: @QuantumSpace and W*-algebras, and C*-categories... It's not exactly what OP is asking, but it is certainly in that spirit

Comment: Thanks @fosco, I'll look into it. Especially chapters 3 & 15 look appealing.

Comment: I just found this through the related questions sidebar, but have you checked this article and its follow-up: https://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-25-2/25J2Castillo.pdf?

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you for your comment. This paper is an excellent resource for Banach *spaces*. There is also part II of this article published in 2022. Castillo and Sanchez also wrote a book, which came out earlier this year, titled "Homological Methods in Banach Space Theory". If only there were a book that covered Banach algebra categories and their subcategories similarly.

Comment: @OnurOktay This feeling is why new books are written :) Become an expert and write this book yourself!

Comment: @QuantumSpace :) Sir, I'm afraid this bar is too high for me. I'm afraid I'll wait for a real expert to write a book on the subject (perhaps the time is ripe for a grad textbook), and solicit/nag the good folks gently here for honest ideas by the meantime. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Some recommended books:

(1) "Completely bounded maps and operator algebras" by Paulsen. In particular, chapter 15 contains a nice chapter about Hamana's theory of injective envelopes of operator spaces, a theory that has attracted much attention the past few years. I suggest complementing this chapter with Hamana's original papers, which are quite readable.

(2) "Compact quantum groups and their representation category". This is the reference book for the study of $C^*$-categories that admit a monoidal structure. Roughly, such a category has Banach spaces as morphism spaces and one can use techniques from C*-algebras to study these categories. Important (but not all) examples of such categories arise as the representation category of the so called compact quantum groups (which generalise compact topological groups), which explains the title of the book. This book is not easy though, but very rewarding once you get through it.

(3) "Amenable Banach algebras" by Runde. Maybe not exactly what you have in mind, but probably worth skimming through. For example, it has a chapter on homological algebra for Banach spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Paulsen and Runde are leading figures in their field and the books you've mentioned are perhaps considered modern classics by people like me. I am sure that the categorical aspects are known to the leading people in the operator spaces & Banach co/homology. We can add more books (as well as articles) to this list, which include injectivity, projectivity, co/completeness, etc. in the context when necessary. However, none of these great books possess primarily a categorical point of view to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the second book in your itemized list. Honestly I am not familiar with quantum groups (I knew only that they are not actual groups). I just had a copy & will look into it. Thanks for the recommendation.